# searching and editing an XML file using python

Tags: python, xml, file, lxml, elementtree

ive had problems trying to search through an xml file for the text within all of the  tags in this xml file. The python script needs to be able to increment the last number of each version tag by 1 e.g. 2.22.0.4 becomes 2.22.0.5

Can someone give me an outline of the the type of python code needed to perform this task?

here is the xml:

```
    <build>
<defaultGoal>deploy</defaultGoal>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>   
    <artifactId>my_plugin</artifactId>   
    <version>9.9</version> 
    <executions>
        <execution>           
            <id>unpack</id>       
            <phase>process</phase>           
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.11.29</version>
                <type>zip</type>
                <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.9.10</version>
                <type>zip</type>
                <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
                <version>0.19.9.10</version>
                <type>zip</type>
                <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.9.9</version>
                <type>zip</type>
                <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.9.10</version>
                <type>zip</type>
                <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.9.10</version>
                <type>zip</type>
            <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
                <version>0.15.29.10</version>
                <type>zip</type>
            <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>         
        </artifactItems>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Try [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

If your target node is only `version`, you can simply loop through the `tree` and edit the `text` attribute on the fly, like so (I use `lxml`) in my example code, other libraries should be fairly similar:

```
In [1]: import lxml.etree as et

In [2]: root = et.parse("sample.xml")

In [3]: tree = root.getroot()

In [4]: for node in tree.iter("version"):
   ...:     v = node.text
   ...:     v = v.split(".")
   ...:     if len(v) > 1: # make sure version does exist in node
   ...:         node.text = '.'.join(v[:-1]) + '.' + str(int(v[-1]) + 1)
   ...:
```

---

```
In [5]: print et.tostring(tree)
<build>
<defaultGoal>deploy</defaultGoal>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>my_plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.10</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>unpack</id>
<phase>process</phase>
<goals>
<goal>unpack</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<artifactItems>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
<version>0.0.11.30</version>
<type>zip</type>
<outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
</artifactItem>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
<version>0.1.9.11</version>
<type>zip</type>
<outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
</artifactItem>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
<version>0.19.9.11</version>
<type>zip</type>
<outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
</artifactItem>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
<version>0.1.9.10</version>
<type>zip</type>
<outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
</artifactItem>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
<version>0.1.9.11</version>
<type>zip</type>
<outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
</artifactItem>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
<version>0.5.9.11</version>
<type>zip</type>
<outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
</artifactItem>
<artifactItem>
<groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
<artifactId>myfile</artifactId>
<version>0.15.29.11</version>
<type>zip</type>
<outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
</artifactItem>
</artifactItems>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Once you locate the `version` nodes, simply assign `.text` attribute to new value -- where I just split it by `.` and increment last part then join them back.

Hope this helps.